# do until loop logic in R

Tags: r, while-loop, repeat, do-while

I have a function fk, I have another function calc where I pass 2 values x and y. I wanted to do the following, until fk(x)*fk(y) <0, I want to double the interval (y-x). How would I accomplish this in `R`. I'm struggling on logic, any help would be greatly appreciated,

```
fk <- function(x) {
    return((x*x)-(3*x)+4)
}

calc <- function(x,y) {  
    g <- fk(x)*fk(y)

    until g < 0 do 
    double the interval (y-x)
}
```

Comment: How can we double the interval if `x` and `y` are passed in as separate parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use something along these lines:

```
calc <- function(x,y) { 
    while (TRUE) {
        g <- fk(x)*fk(y)
        if (g < 0) {
            break
        }
        // otherwise double interval (y-x)
    }
}
```

As I mentioned in my comment, it is not clear how you want to adjust the values for `x` and `y` in order to "double" the interval.  Once you figure that out, you can add the required code to the loop.

Answer (score 2):

You could do that using `while`:

```
while (fk(x) * fk(y) < 0) {
    interval <- (y-x) * 2
}
```

Your function would look like:

```
calc <- function(x,y) {  

 while (fk(x) * fk(y) < 0) {
        interval <- (y-x) * 2
    }
}
```